# Проблема с функцией mail

Tags: php

Первый день изучаю php. Установил Denwer, решил посмотреть как работает отправка писем. Создал простой скрипт с функцией Mail:

```
<?php
    mail("meresh976@yandex.ru","Hello world","Привет");
?>
```

Но при запуске, браузер выдает ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
> '@' in Z:\home\test2.ru\www\send.php
> on line 2

Поиск в гугле результатов не дал. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Вы или показали не весь код, или изменили его тут. Потому что, при такой записи, не должно быть синтаксических ошибок.

Comment: Это весь код. Ничего не менял

Comment: @Sizel, ну нет тут никаких синтаксических ошибок.

Comment: Странно.Попробую денвер переустановить

Answer (score 1):

[@Sizel](/users/20186/sizel), лучше вообще удалите Денвер, а возьмите какой-нибудь инструмент получше: [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/ru/index.html), [Winginx](http://winginx.com/ru/), [Open Server](http://open-server.ru/) и т.д. Я бы рекомендовал последний, но выбор за вами.

Comment: Установил Open Server. Все работает!